# Program crashes while trying to get a string from file and access indvidual letters in the string

Tags: c, string, loops, pointers, file-handling

I am creating a C program to convert all lower case to upper case and vice versa. In the C program, I am trying to get a string from a text file and access each of the characters. But my program crashes. What is the error that I am doing here? Below is my code:

```
 //Program to read contents from a source file and convert the lower case characters to a upper case and vice versa and print it on a target file

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void merge(FILE *fp,int n,char *fdata,FILE *fpr)
{
    char change_case[1000];
    int loop = 0;

    while(fgets(fdata,n,fp)!=NULL)
    {
        fgets(fdata,n,fp);

        //printf("%s",fdata);

        if ((*(fdata+loop) >= 65) && (*(fdata+loop) <= 90))
        {
            printf("%c",*(fdata+loop));
            change_case[loop] = *(fdata+loop)+32;
        }
        else if ((*(fdata+loop) >= 97) && ((*fdata+loop) <= 122))
        {
            printf("%c",*(fdata+loop));
            change_case[loop] = *(fdata+loop)-32;
        }
        else
        {
            change_case[loop] = *(fdata+loop);
        }
        loop++;

        fpr = fopen("Text File 3.dat","w");

        if (fpr == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error in accessing / writing the target file"); 
        }
        else
        {
            fputs(change_case,fpr);
            printf("Line written successfully : %s\n", change_case);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    FILE *sfp, *tfp; //declaring a file pointer for source file and target file
    char *fdata;
    int n = 1000;
    sfp = fopen("Text File 1.txt","r");

    if (sfp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error in reading the source file\n");
    }

    else
    {
        merge(sfp,n,fdata,tfp);
    }   

    fclose(sfp);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: where are you allocating the memory to fdata?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2173917)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In function  `void merge(FILE *fp,int n,char *fdata,FILE *fpr)`-

```
fgets(fdata,n,fp);         // you tend to write at invalid location
```

memory is not allocated to `fdata` . You need to allocate memory to it .

```
fdata=malloc(n);     // check its return and also remember to free it
```

*Note* - Don't use [`while!feof(fp)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) .

You can do this instead -

```
while(fgets(fdata,n,fp)!=NULL)
{
     // your code
}
```

Comment: @KiranCK  If there is  large data then you would need to allocate more memory . If updated the answer allocating more memory .

Comment: The characters in the input file are less than 100

Comment: @KiranCK I don't get carsh . You sure this is the code ?

Comment: @KiranCK  You should not update original code in question . And please dont cast result of `malloc`.

Comment: I have edited and pasted the code with the updates you have pointed. Still it crashes. I use Code blocks with Borland C 5.5.1 as compiler

Comment: The test file that it points to contains 27 characters on 3 lines. A line a blank line and the last line: Text file content:  Hello!. This is a test file.

Comment: @KiranCK  Well , I ran it but doesn't gave me any crash .